# How to Give Routes Different Edge Colours in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, routes, colors, networkx, edges

I am trying to create a railnet with different routes on a map. I am using `Networkx` and I am having trouble with providing different color for the routes(connections). Below, you can find the code that I have now.
The code now works in the sense that it does not give errors and provides a map with all the nodes and connections but it does not give different colors to the connections.

I also tried to draw the network edges in the loop but this did not work. I am very new to networkx and this is my first time using it.

**Note:** We are working as a group in github and the `route.route` is equal to a list of such form:

```
["Schiedam Centrum", "Delft", "Den Haag Centraal", "Gouda", "Rotterdam Alexander", "Rotterdam Centraal", "Dordrecht"]
```

Thanks in advance for having a look :)

```
def visualise(station_list, connections, network_object):
        
    # Create a graph object
    G = nx.Graph()

    # Extract x, y coordinates, and station names
    x = []
    y = []
    station_names = []

    for station in station_list:
        name, lon, lat = station.split(',')
        if name in G.nodes: 
            continue
        x.append(float(lat))
        y.append(float(lon))
        station_names.append(name)

        # Add nodes to the graph
        G.add_node(name, pos=(float(lat), float(lon)))

    print(G.nodes)


    # Create the map
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 20))

    # Draw the stations as nodes
  **  pos = {name: (lon, lat) for name, lon, lat in zip(station_names, x, y)}
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color='yellow', node_size=100, edgecolors='black')

    all_routes = network_object.routes 
    colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w', '0.5', '0.75', '0.25', '0.1', '0.9', '0.3',   '0.7', '0.2', '0.8', '0.4', '0.6', '0.0']

    for route in all_routes: 
        for color in colors: 
            new_route = route.route 
            route_color = color

            for a, b in zip(new_route, new_route[1:]):
                G.add_edge(a.name, b.name)

            for edge in G.edges: 
                if edge in new_route: 
                    edge['color'] = route_color**


    # Add labels to the stations
    labels = {name: name for name in station_names}
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, font_size=8)

    # Draw the connections between stations as edges
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=2)

    # Set map boundaries
    plt.xlim(min(x) - 0.05, max(x) + 0.05)
    plt.ylim(min(y) - 0.03, max(y) + 0.03)

    # Add gridlines and title
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.title("Stations Map")

    # Show the map
    plt.show()
```

As said before I have tried to draw network edges in a loop. I am able to modify all edges in the draw edges, but then all will be the same color. I have not been able so far to modify edges individually.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is your entire code the commands of method `def visualize`? If not try to reformat a bit, otherwise it is more difficult for someone to see what this code is doing